# How to run Python3 script from php on CPanel?

Tags: php, python-3.x, cpanel

I have a python script that i want to run from index.php and they both are in the same directory.
The problem is that there's no output shown on the page(index.php).

- I am running the page on a CPanel shared hosting from GoDaddy.
- I have the permissions `-rwx` for both the files.
- There's no error in running the python3 script file from the terminal.
- The same files run smoothly on my computer's localhost but not on the CPanel.
- Am able to run bash files using the same php code.

I have tried using `system()` in php to call the python3 script file but this doesn't seems to work.

index.php:

```php
<?php
    $comm = "python3 test.py";
    echo $comm;
    $output = system($comm);
    echo "\n";
    print($output);
?>
```

test.py:

```py
print ("Hello")
```

Current Output:

```
python3 test.py
```

I expect the output to be:

```
python3 test.py Hello
```

Comment: Try shell_exec instead of system

Comment: Thanx @lucas-meine. But ```shell_exec``` also doesn't works. It also gives the same output as ```system```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use shell_exec to run your python code like that

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

and the first line in the python file should be

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Don't forget to give your python file the privileges

```
chmod +x test.py
```